# androidで動画ファイルのダウンロードする場合

Tags: android, java

現在Androidアプリをjava言語で開発中なのですが
サーバーとのやりとりについてです
アプリを通しサーバーに置いておいた動画ファイルをhttpURLconnectionを利用しAndroid端末にダウンロードしたいのですが下記のプログラムではテキストのダウンロードしかされません
どうプログラムすれば動画ファイルをダウンロードできるようになるか ヒントをください
因みにサーバーはphpです

```
//HTTP通信
public class HttpEx extends Activity   
    implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final static int WC = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    private final static int MP = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    private final static String TAG_READ = "read";
    private EditText editText;
    private String   text;
    private Handler  handler = new Handler();
    
    //テキストファイルのURLの指定(1)
    private final static String URL =
        "http://localhost/test/img01.jpg";
        
    //アクティビティ起動時に呼ばれる
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //レイアウトの生成
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(layout);      
        
        //エディットテキストの生成
        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setText("");
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MP, WC));
        layout.addView(editText);

        //ボタンの生成
        layout.addView(makeButton("HTTP通信", TAG_READ));
    }   

    //ボタンの生成
    private Button makeButton(String text, String tag) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(text);
        button.setTag(tag);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WC, WC));
        return button;
    }

    //ボタンクリック時に呼ばれる
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tag = (String)v.getTag();
        if (TAG_READ.equals(tag)) {
            //スレッドの生成(4)
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {
                //HTTP通信
                try {
                    text = new String(http2data(URL));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    text = null;
                }
                //ハンドラの生成(5)
                handler.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {
                    if (text != null) {
                        editText.setText(text);
                    } else {
                        editText.setText("読み込み失敗しました。");
                    }
                }});
            }});
            thread.start();
        }
    }     
    
    //HTTP通信
    public static byte[] http2data(String path) throws Exception {
        byte[] w=new byte[1024]; 
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            //HTTP接続のオープン(2)
            URL url = new URL(path);
            c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();
            in = c.getInputStream();
            
            //バイト配列の読み込み
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while (true) {
                int size = in.read(w);
                if (size <= 0) break;
                out.write(w, 0, size);
            }
            out.close();

            //HTTP接続のクローズ(3)
            in.close();
            c.disconnect();
            return out.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                if (c != null) c.disconnect();
                if (in != null) in.close();
                if (out != null) out.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: うまく行かないとは、例外が発生するという事でしょうか？

Comment: 恥ずかしながら動画ファイルの場合に
どのようなプログラムを書けばよいのかわからないんです
HttpURLconnectionを利用して動画ファイルのやりとりは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 動画のやりとりにも色々あります。ファイルをサーバに置いてHTTP経由でダウンロードする物、ffserver等を使ってRTSPの様なプロトコルを使って動画をやりとりする方法等、多岐にわたります。HTTP経由のダウンロードなのであれば、「うまくいかない」と仰るからにはどこかしらで例外が発生していると思われますがいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 投稿文追加したので見てくれたら幸いです

Comment: 「うまくいかない」と表現されている部分を、具体的に発生している事象／エラーメッセージ／動作の説明に置き換えてください、

Comment: 「動画ファイルのダウンロード」とは、ストリーミング再生のことなのでしょうか？それとも単純なファイルのダウンロードで、ダウンロードした後のデータの扱い方に困っているということでしょうか？

Comment: ストリーミングではなくファイルのダウンロードです
また ダウンロードの後の処理ではなく
ダウンロードする処理をどうすればよいのか根本的にわかっていないのですが ご教授お願いできませんか

Comment: 質問文には動画ファイルとありますが、提示コードのダウンロード対象URLは拡張子jpg（静止画像ファイル）となっています。意図通りですか？また実際の動作「テキストのダウンロードしかされない」というのは、具体的にどのようなテキスト（中身）がダウンロードされたのでしょう？

Answer (score 2):

[DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) を使用するとネットワーク上の動画を端末内に保存することができます。